# How to catch a user who sent a message in chat

Tags: laravel

I'm having trouble showing users who have sent messages to other users. See below to understand what I mean:

My Table Messages:

```
Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('de_user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('de_user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->integer('para_user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('para_user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->text('message');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I have the page where it will display users who have sent messages to another member:

```
<section class="conversations">
                <a href="https://www.example.com/profile/messages/username" class="conversation ">
                    <div class="info">
                        <div class="name ">
                            Marcos
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="date"><span aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-circle"></span> 3 months ago
                    </div>
                </a>
  </section>
```

But to display who sent the messages, I need to access the `id` of who received it in the `Message` table. Also, I need to get the user who sent it. My problem is that I don't know how to identify who sent it once. So that I get a collection of all messages.

Here's how I'm doing it:

```
public function msgs(Request $request) {

      $msg = Message::where('para_user_id', $request->user()->id)->get();

      return view('msgs',compact('msg'));
        
    }
```

But how can I receive many messages from the same user. This solution does not work. I need to catch a single time who sent the message to me, regardless of how many messages were sent. And so, only return the users who sent me messages.

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work

```js
    $msg = Message::where('para_user_id', $request->user()->id)->get()->unique('de_user_id')->values();
```

Comment: Certainly not a friend. It will only return 1. And there are several users who may have sent messages to me.

Comment: @1001SongsClips I have edited the answer. is that working for you ?